# How to improve performance?

Tags: java, rally

I have code to remove access from Rally for user

we have around 2000 projects in rally

i have below logic implemented

- read user list from the csv file
- loop thru each user
- fetch user's project permission url - write into text file
- read user permission - loop thru
- remove access

  ```
  try {

      QueryRequest usrRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
      usrRequest.setLimit(9999);
      usrRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FirstName","LastName","UserName","UserPermissions"));
      usrRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", userID));
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      QueryResponse usrResp = restApi.query(usrRequest);

      if (usrResp.wasSuccessful()) {

          for (JsonElement result : usrResp.getResults()) {

              JsonObject usrJson = result.getAsJsonObject();

              try {

                  userName = usrJson.get("UserName").getAsString();

                  if (userName.contains(userID)){

                      String userRef = usrJson.get("_ref").getAsString();
                      GetRequest userRequest = new GetRequest(userRef);
                      GetResponse userResponse = restApi.get(userRequest);
                      JsonObject userObj = userResponse.getObject();

                      JsonArray userPermArray = userObj.get("UserPermissions").getAsJsonArray();

                      for (int iter=0; iter<userPermArray.size(); iter++){

                          JsonObject prjPerm = userPermArray.get(iter).getAsJsonObject();

                          if (prjPerm.get("_type").getAsString().equalsIgnoreCase("ProjectPermission")){
                              tmp = prjPerm.get("_refObjectName").getAsString();
                              strArrray = tmp.split(" ");
                              last=strArrray[strArrray.length-1];
                              prjName = tmp.substring(0, tmp.length() - last.length()); 
                              prjRef = prjPerm.get("_ref").getAsString();

                              if (prjName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("MyLogins Default")){}
                              else{
                                  //if the project permission is not editor then add that project
                                  if((checkUserStatusToThisProject(restApi, prjRef, userRef))){
                                      //prjPermList.put(prjName.trim(), prjRef);
                                      bw.write(prjName.trim()+"="+prjRef.trim());
                                      bw.newLine();
                                      //
                                  }
                              }
                          }

                      } // end of for loop

                  } // end of if

              }catch (Exception e) {
                  log.info("Error in fetching project list for user to remove : "+e.getStackTrace());
                  // TODO: handle exception
              }
          }// end of for loop

      } // end of if

      bw.close();
  }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- the above code is taking 3 hours for 4 users
- i believe i am doing some mistake in fetching user project permission list
- in checkUserStatusForThisProject function - i am checking what type of role this user has to this project? - if he is viewer, then i have to remove, otherwise (Editor) no.

is my logic correct ? or any other quick way to remove access ?

Pls Help

Thanks
VG

Comment: You need some kind of benchmark to find out which part of the code makes it that slow. Then you can try to optimize it. There are many method calls which could cause it. We would have to guess which one it is...

Comment: What does the code for the checkUserStatusToThisProject() method look like? Some instrumentation as suggested by jlordo above would be great too.